# Quick Equation to solve Camera rotation based on parent scale

Tags: math

I've got a camera attached to a parent that scales causing the camera to "zoom". I want the camera to tilt more at a lower scale. I need an equation that will tilt the camera between the min and max based on the scale of the parent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated =)

See the diagram below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading it right, the Scale varies from 0.1 to 1.0, and you want the Angle to vary from 20 to 40 degrees. Right?

A simple linear formula would look like

```
CurrentAngle = MinAngle + (CurrentScale - MinScale) * (MaxAngle - MinAngle) / (MaxScale - MinScale)
             = 20 + (CurrentScale - 0.1) * (40 - 20) / (1 - 0.1)
             = 20 + (CurrentScale - 0.1) * 20 / 0.9
```

So if you use 0.64 as the `CurrentScale`, as in your example above, you'd get

```
             = 20 + (0.64 - 0.1) * 20 / 0.9
             = 32
```

Linear is the simplest mathematically, but if your application is animated or needs to change the angle faster on one end or the other of your scale, you may get a more polished result from using a formula with a curve to it (logarithmic, parabolic or exponential, maybe?).

Comment: If you want the camera to point to the same location, a little trig is needed instead.

Comment: This works pretty well and simply. I changed it a bit to only rotate the angle after 0.25 scale so I got a nice curve now when you zoom in close.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of scale, you need distances. Consider the variable verical distance `y` and the target horizontal distance `x` which you want to keep fixed. The angle of the camera `θ` is related by

```
θ = ATAN(y/x)*(180/π)
```

Given the end conditions `y_1/x = TAN(20°)` and `y_2/x = TAN(40°)` one finds that

```
y_2 = TAN(40°)/TAN(20°)*y_1 = 2.3054*y_1
x = COS(20°)/SIN(20°)*y_1 = 2.7474*y_1
```

The initial height `y_1` is required to compute the horizontal distance `x`.

Now since `s=0.1` means `y(s)=y_1` and `s=1.0` means `y(s)=y_2` then

```
y(s) = 10/9*(y_2-y_1)*s+(10*y_1-y_2)/9
     = y_1*10*(1-s)/9+y_1*(10*s-1)*TAN(40°)/(9*TAN(20°))
     = y_1*(1.450*s+0.855)

TAN(θ) = y(s)/x
TAN(θ) = 10*(1-s)*TAN(20°)/9+(10*s-1)*TAN(40°)/9
```

**Use this:**

```
θ(s) = 180/π*ATAN(0.5279*s+0.3112)
```

With the following example values

```
s      θ(s)
0.1    20°
0.55   31°
1.0    40°
```

Comment: I'm gonna mark this as the answer since it seems more correct than just a working version. I'll prob come and use this solution anyway lol.